# Show UIViewController partially over a UIViewController with Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to show a UIViewController over a UIViewController from the top of the screen (for example, when a button is pressed) and I would like it to be shown only of a part of the screen (for example 50%).

Can it be done?

Comment: You could have a `UIView` animate over the top and use a container view to hold the second `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

One view controller can present another view controller modally.
The visual style of the presentation can be one of the predefined ones from UIKit, or you can set

```
presentingViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
```

and then implement the custom animated transitioning which is not a trivial task so its best if you find a step by step guide or watch a WWDC video for that. In the custom implemented transitioning class, it is you who controls the position of the presented view that belongs to the presentedViewController.